# I can't use input in Mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I how defined a procedure in MySql which has an input and input will be a name of column that will be added to table 'test1' but sql names that column input instead of using the value of input .how can i do this in the right way?

```
DELIMITER 
CREATE PROCEDURE p1
(IN input CHAR(20))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE test1
ADD COLUMN input char(20);
END 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql to do this.

Comment: @P.Salmon whats that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should google dynamic sql and read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
In the meantime here's an example.

```
drop procedure if exists  p;
alter table users 
    drop column abc;
DELIMITER  $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p
(IN input CHAR(20))
BEGIN
#ALTER TABLE test1
#ADD COLUMN input char(20);
set @sql = concat('alter table users add column ',input,' char(20);');
select @sql;
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call p('abc');
describe users;

MariaDB [sandbox]> call p('abc');
+--------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+
| alter table users add column abc char(20); |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> describe users;
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| userName            | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| photo               | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| status              | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| ts                  | datetime    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| events_participated | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| fb_uid              | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Column_name         | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| post_type           | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| password            | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| abc                 | char(20)    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```